# Removing loading icon after all components rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In an analytics app, I have a loading icon(modal overlay in fact), which is being added to the DOM as the first item of the rendered elements (covers everything else).

The issue with that is that it's the first thing NOT being rendered, too, which means that when the actual app loads, it removes the loading modal first, and there's a fraction of a second when the user sees a yet not fully updated page. Only after this fraction of a second (~400ms perhaps), does he get the final state of the page.

Is there some clean way to set the state of this 'pageLoading' in such a way, that it's only removed after everything else is rendered? Or should I handle a loading icon/modal in a different manner?

A small pseudo-react-sample (not actual app as its huge):

```
this.state = {
  pageLoading: false,
  data: null,
}

ComponentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    pageLoading: true,
  }, () => {
  data = getData();
  this.setState({
    data: data,
    pageLoading: false,
  })})
}

render() {
  let components = []
  if (this.state.pageLoading) {
    components.push(<div>LOADING</div>)
  }
  components.push(<Dashboard data='data'/>)
  return(
    <div>
      components
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can't give specific advice without seeing the code, but have you tried clearing the loading state when the main app mounts?

Comment: the components in div should be in `{}` as that is a part of Javascript and you should use loop as `components` is an array.